# .WPF Application builds <appname>.dll.config instead of an <appname>.exe.config

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to create an app.config that allows my WPF application to probe into a local lib folder. However, I am not getting an exe version of my app.config when building my project. Renaming the .dll file does not work either.

Edit: I am using .NET Core

Comment: there are two WPF project types at play here. one is an application (.exe) and the other is a library (.dll). visual studio has built in templates for both project types: WPF App and WPF User Control Library, respectively.

when you build an application with an app.config, you get a *.exe and a *.exe.config, and when you build a class library with an app.config, you get a *.dll and a *.dll.config.

my guess is you're building a user control library when you mean to be building an application.

Comment: That makes sense; however, my output type is set to Windows Application. Is there another setting affecting my build to build a control library? Additionally, I get an <appname>.exe output but a dll.config.

Comment: the output we are finding in bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1 is similar to all compiled dotnet core apps. in fact, if we clean/delete the bin folder then run `dotnet build` in the project folder, we get the same results. if we make a .net core console app, add an App.config, and build, we will observe the same behavior. similarly, if we clean/delete the console app's bin folder then run `dotnet build` in the project folder, same results again. all that to say, this is expected behavior and ubiquitous for dotnet core apps. regardless, we can still read the config via `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`.

Comment: Can ConfigurationManager.AppSettings be used to probe a path?

Comment: apologies, i understood your question to be "why does WPF Application builds <appname>.dll.config instead of an <appname>.exe.config" so that is what i've attempted to answer.

Comment: No problem; that point was part of the confusion. Thank you for clearing that part up.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Nobody has addressed the problem that my app.config in my APP (WinCal.exe) project folder gets built and ends up as a WinCal.dll.config file in the bin directory. It makes no sense.

Comment: @JeffH In .NET Core, WPF/WinForms apps store their logic in .dll file instead of .exe. Exe file is create by dotnet as a native bootstrapper to start the managed dll. So it's appropriate that the app.config is named .dll.config.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek, now this makes sense. I did notice that the app had the DLL. Now I understand how it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In .NET Core project the generated exe is just a bootstrapper. Your application resides in a DLL file. So it makes sense that the config is also associated with that DLL.